# saving a float to a FloatField Django model, why coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found

Tags: python, django, unicode

I have a model:

```
 class Conditions(models.Model):
        date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        temperature = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        humidity = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.temperature
```

I have data to load into the model imported from google docs.I'm saving is like so:

```
conditions_obj = Conditions.objects.get_or_create(
                    date_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                    temperature=float(row[1]),
                    humidity=float(row[2]))
```

When I do this I get this error, and I'm not sure why:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found
```

Do my temperature values need to be saved as a string, because if I do that then things work. Just seems bazaar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not saving: the problem is your `__unicode__` method. As the name clearly implies, it needs to return a unicode value, not a float.

You could convert it explicitly:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.temperature)
```

Comment: I guess I thought the __unicode__(self) would return the unicode string. Thanks a lot!